# Node.js and express templates seem to work without specifying a path, how

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js and express, I have a project that uses the vash template engine and I put the templates in a 'views' folder.  I don't specify the location of the templates, i.e. I do not have  app.set('views', './views'); in the code and yet it works. I can find no mention of 'views' being a default folder for templates,is it?

I'm using express 4.13.1

Answer (score 1):

This is default configuration set in the `node_modules/express/lib/application.js`:

```
this.set('views', resolve('views'));
```

Answer (score -1):

"./views" is effectively the default value for the `views` option.
You can see it in the docs: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.settings.table